# Lua - coroutines - official example

Tags: multithreading, lua, coroutine

on this website
http://www.lua.org/pil/9.2.html there is an example of a coroutine.

I wrote the same example without coroutine, and I don't see any advantage of coroutines in the official example. Is there even an advantage of using coroutines on that example?

Same without coroutine (I replaced `io.input` with `math.random`)

```
local line = 1

function Produce ()
    local value  = math.random(10)
    return value
end

function Filter ()
    while true do
      local value = Produce()
      value       = string.format("%3d %s", line, value)    
      line        = line + 1
      return value
    end
end

function Consum ()
    while true do
        local value = Filter()
        print(value, "\n")     
    end
end

Consum()
```

Comment: Your loop in `Filter` is pointless. It only ever executes once.

Comment: Yes this is correct, the loop breaks because it returns a value

Comment: I think when I read this question initially I assumed it was "what is the point of coroutines" but looking at it again I think I may have misread it. Is the question more specifically whether **that** example is useful in some fashion (when it could equally well be written without them)?